# How to call a method just after authentication and just before logout? (Spring Security)

Tags: security, spring, authentication, spring-security

I want to write a row in a db every time a user logs into my application (that uses spring security), and to add the logout time to that row when he logs out, in order to register the number of access and the duration of the session.

I thought there was some Post-Authentication Filter, but I checked the documentation and couldn't find any reference of it.

Is too invasive to write a filter and add it to the spring security filter chain?

Is there some another workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming You're using Spring Security 3.0.x and securing a web application, check out:

- [AuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html) used by `AuthenticationProcessingFilter` for actions on successful login.
- And [LogoutSuccessHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutSuccessHandler.html) used by `LogoutFilter` for actions on successful logout.

Comment: The problem in doing this is that I have to rewrite how the application forwards the user after login and logout. I don't want to change it, just add  some code to register it on DB. How can I preserve the original forwarding?

Comment: @jdanielnd: Extend the [SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler.html) instead of directly implementing the `LogoutSuccessHandler` interface.